# Add column in WP user but it goes wrong

Tags: plugin-development, columns

I add a column to users page, it goes wrong when checkbox is not in correct position. This is my code, can you help me to move checkbox to the correct position?

```
public static function user_register_columns( $columns ) {
    // create a new array with account just after username, then everything else
    $new_columns = array();
    if ( isset($columns['username']) ) {
        $new_columns['username'] = $columns['username'];
        unset($columns['username']);
    }
    $new_columns['account'] = self::__( 'Account' );
    $new_columns = array_merge($new_columns, $columns);
    return $new_columns;
}
public static function user_column_display( $empty='', $column_name, $id ) {
    $account = WP_ABC_Account::get_instance( $id );

    if ( !$account )
        return; // return for that temp post

    switch ( $column_name ) {
    case 'account':
        $account_id = $account->get_ID();
        $user_id = $account->get_user_id_for_account( $account_id );
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $get_name = $account->get_name();
        $name = ( strlen( $get_name ) <= 1  ) ? '' : $get_name;

        //Build row actions
        $actions = array(
            'edit'    => sprintf( '<a href="#">'.self::__( 'Manage' ).'</a>', $account_id ),
            'payments'    => sprintf( '<a href="#">'.self::__( 'Payments' ).'</a>', $account_id ),
            'gifts'    => sprintf( '<a href="#">'.self::__( 'Gifts').'</a>', $account_id )
        );

        //Return the title contents
        return sprintf( self::__( '%1$s <span style="color:silver">(account&nbsp;id:%2$s)</span> <span style="color:silver">(user&nbsp;id:%3$s)</span>%4$s' ),
            $name,
            $account_id,
            $user_id,
            WP_List_Table::row_actions( $actions )
        );
        break;

    default:
        // code...
        break;
    }
}
```

Result look like this, checkbox is not in correct position. It must always on left.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have hooked into `manage_users_columns`. Probably your array_merge is causing the problem. Instead of using `$new_columns` as the 1st parameter, use it as the 2nd as given below.

```
$new_columns = array_merge ( $columns, $new_columns );
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but result looks not good too. There is space next to checkbox. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TLSRv.png

Comment: The space is for name column. Since you do not have any data, it's an empty column.